# Javadoc setting validates, but Eclipse cannot display

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I've setup javadoc location of a jar in eclipse. It validates and opens in browser ok.

But when I hover a method, it still says no javadoc is attached.

I tried to rebuild workspace, restart eclipse etc.

Eclipse v: **Kepler**.

I'm sure it was answered before, but I couldn't find the right answer with keywords valid, validated, validates etc.

[image: javadoc setting validated]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse version Kepler.